# Store values from for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I have a large dataframe with scaffold annotations (example rows):

```
 gff <- data.frame(seqid = c("Scaffold21", "Scaffold21", "Scaffold21", "Scaffold31", "Scaffold31", "Scaffold11561", "Scaffold11561"),
                    start = c(4179,16947,18411,25986,45575, 52,54100),
                    end = c(4697,17667,19643,32223,46657,1572,54627),
                    attributes = c("tRNA","sRNA","exon","rRNA","mRNA","mRNA","exon"))
```

And I have another dataframe with RNA coordinates (Example rows)

```
RNA <- data.frame(seqid = c("Scaffold21", "Scaffold11561"),
                  start = c(17047,1380))
```

I've been trying to filter the first dataframe to annotate the RNAs in the second one using:

```
scaffold <- unique(RNA$seqid)
coord <- RNA$start
n <- length(scaffold)*length(coord)
output <- matrix(ncol = ncol(gff), nrow = n)
myfunc <- function(x,y){gff[gff$seqid == x & gff$start <= y & gff$end >= y,]}

for (x in scaffold) {
  for (y in coord) {
    test = myfunc(x, y)
    output <- test
  }
}
```

The problem here is that only the information about the last x,y pair is being stored. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me to fix this.

The output that I'm getting now looks like:
|seqid|start|end|
|:----|:----|:--|
|Scaffold11561|52|1572|mRNA|

Ideally, it would look like:

| seqid | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scaffold21 | 16947 | 17667 |
| Scaffold11561 | 52 | 1572 |

Comment: Without access to your data it's hard to know exactly what is going on. But it looks to me that in every iteration of the y loop your are overwriting/replacing `output` using `test`. You are specifying output as a matrix (I presume of the expected size)? So in the loop you'd have to also specify where in the matrix each of the values should be stored.

Comment: (I've added toy data that works just as my entire data) 
Yes, that's exactly what's going on. The output is being overwritten, and I don't know how to stop this. I haven't been able to find a way to specify where in the matrix each of the values should be stored.

Comment: You could try i <- 0L and i <- i+1L in the inner for-loop. output[i,] <- ...

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Comment: @mmn Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. I got the error message: Error in output[i, ] <- test : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
Also, I added my expected output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given your sample code you could use something like:

```
scaffold <- unique(RNA$seqid)
coord <- RNA$start
n <- length(scaffold)*length(coord)
output <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(gff), nrow = n)) #matrix can only store one type
myfunc <- function(x,y){gff[gff$seqid == x & gff$start <= y & gff$end >= y,]}

i <- 0L


for (x in scaffold) {
  for (y in coord) {
    i <- i + 1L
    test <- myfunc(x, y)
    if(nrow(test) != 1) next
    output[i, ] <- test
  }
}
output <- na.omit(output)
```

This is probably slow if have a lot of rows. You could also think about using joins. For example:

```
a<- merge(gff, RNA, by = "seqid")
a[(a$start.x <= a$start.y) & (a$end >= a$start.y),]
```

Comment: Many thanks! Both suggestions (especially the 2nd one) work perfectly